# PYTHON Pandas - Using Pandas Styling for dataframe based on values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles, highlight

I´m dealing with this challenge quite a while and I couldn´t come up with a decent solution.

I have two dataframes with the same shape. 
[image: Dataframe 1]

[image]

[image]

The thing I want to do is, is to color dataframe 1 based on the values contained in dataframe 2.

I´m able to color Dataframe 2 based on its own values but I couldn´t manage to transfer the 'Styling' to Dataframe 1.

Here is my code for this:

```
df1 = ...
df2 = ...

def apply_color(val):

    colors = {1: 'green',2: 'blue', 3: 'yellow', 4: 'orange', 5: 'grey'}

    return 'background-color: {}'.format(colors[val]) if val else ''

df2.style.applymap(df2)
```

Can anyone guide me to finalize this? :-)

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,
MG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with `get` by dict for `DataFrame` for colors and pass to [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9],
         'D':[1,3,5],


})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[1,np.nan,4],
         'C':[np.nan,2,np.nan],
         'D':[1,3,np.nan],

})
```

---

```
def apply_color(x):
    colors = {1: 'green',2: 'blue', 3: 'yellow', 4: 'orange', 5: 'grey'}
    return df2.applymap(lambda val: 'background-color: {}'.format(colors.get(val,'')))

df1.style.apply(apply_color, axis=None)
```

---

[image: pic]

Comment: You are awesome! This works for me!

I only got one question left: How do I handle this error / warning?:
Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py:312: CSSWarning: Unhandled color format: ''

Happens for the cells with no values, i guess in this case ''

Comment: @mgruber - What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas (0.23.4)

Comment: @mgruber - It is weird, for me it working nice, is possible upgade to last version?

Comment: The code with the dataframes you provided is working fine. If I apply it to my actual dataframes the error pops up. Seems like I have empty strings in the cells that don´t contain a number but if I replace the np.nan with empty strings in your code its still working. Is there a way to just define "background color: None" ?!

Comment: @jezreal any ideas?

Comment: @mgruber - How working change `colors.get(val,'')` to `colors.get(val,None)` ?

Comment: @jezreal Brilliant!

Comment: I'm trying something very similar, but I'm confused about how the function apply_color works.  It seems to me that it should be returning the entire df2 dataframe (colored) to each value in df1.

Comment: @danielbrandstetter - It working very simple - helper function return DataFrame filled by strings of styles, elementwise.